# DropDownListFor (data-live-search="true") how do i add?

Tags: html, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Odeyenİd, new SelectList(ViewBag.Musteriler, "İd", "MusteriAdiSoyadi"), new { @class = "selectpicker form-control" })

```
                        <select class="selectpicker form-control" id="number" data-container="body" data-live-search="true" title="Müşteri Seçiniz.." data-hide-disabled="true">
                            @foreach (var person in ViewBag.Musteriler)
                            {
                                <option value="@person.İd"> @person.MusteriAdiSoyadi</option>
                            }
                        </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Odeyenİd, 
    new SelectList(ViewBag.Musteriler, "İd", "MusteriAdiSoyadi"), 
    new { @class = "selectpicker form-control",@data_live_search=... 
})
```